# Entering Rescue mode after formatting Partition containing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, grubrescue

So I Formatted the partition having Ubuntu and when I restarted it said error

```
 no such partition. Entering rescue mode...
```

I tried following the online answers concerning listing all the partitions and then setting the root and the prefix but unfortunately everytime I try to recognize each partition by: `ls (hdX,Y)`.. it outputs `(hdX,Y):Filesystem is unknown`.
I also tried installing Ubuntu from a Flash memory but it outputs `NTLDR is missing` and then directs me to rescue mode. However, I tried booting on another laptop from the same flash memory and it worked.

Comment: Replace `X` and `Y` with proper characters like `a` and `1` e.g. `ls (hda,1)`

Comment: @Faizan yeah I did so ,, I was speaking generally ,, I listed all the partitions : ls (hd0,1), ls (hd0,2) and the rest of them and outputs Filesystem in unknown

Comment: Then you probably have a corrupted partition table, try reinstalling Ubuntu using a DVD if flash memory doesn't work for you!